# Popup window without HorizontalOffset to center in all resolution wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

i have designed a popup window to show it horizontally center and vertically "VerticalOffset="45"". Vertical position is perfect in all resolution but horizontal position is not center aligned. How to make it center aligned for all resolution.

```
<Popup x:Class="....Wpf.Controls.ShowError"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:...Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"  PlacementRectangle="0,0,30,50"
   VerticalOffset="45"
   HorizontalOffset="600" 
   Placement="Bottom"
   PopupAnimation="Fade" AllowsTransparency="True">
<Border Width="500" Height="150" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" >
    <Border Style="{StaticResource ErrorPopupBorderStyle}">
        <TextBlock  x:Name="tbError"  Style="{StaticResource ErrorMessageStyle}"/>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

```
 ShowError pop = new ShowError
        {
            Message = error,
            IsError = true
        };
        pop.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

pop.HorizontalOffset = (MainWindow.Instance.Width / 2) + (border.Width / 2);